# ngRoute error, version conflict

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-routing

After trying to installing an angularjs component and updating all components via bower my routing does not work anymore. I guess it´s some kind of problem with the version of angular js and ngroute, but being new to angular js / bower I am not sure how to fix it, any guidance is appreciated!

Error:

```
[$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $templateRequestProvider <- $templateRequest <- $route <- ngViewDirective
```

Bower file:

```
{
"name": "asclepius",
"version": "0.0.0",
"dependencies": {
 "angular": "^1.3.0",
 "bootstrap": "^3.2.0",
 "angular-animate": "^1.3.0",
 "angular-cookies": "^1.3.0",
 "angular-resource": "^1.3.0",
 "angular-route": "^1.2.0",
 "angular-sanitize": "^1.3.0",
 "angular-touch": "^1.3.0",
 "international-phone-number": "~0.0.7"
},
 "devDependencies": {
 "angular-mocks": "^1.3.0"
},
"appPath": "app",
"moduleName": "asclepiusApp",
"resolutions": {
  "angular": ">=1.2.0"
}
}
```

Comment: Do you know the older version you were using?

Comment: if you're using angular 1.3+ I think you need to use angular-route 1.3+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Happened something similar today to my coworker. He resolved replacing "^1.3.x" to "1.3.x" in "angular-cookies" and "angular-sanitize". Check if changing it in angular-route resolve the problem.

I think this happens since the release of angular 1.4 a few days ago.